# What part of speech is would and why does it seem to have no infinitive?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

I have walked. I will walk. I walk.

All of these immediate verbs have infinitive forms in to walk, to will, to have.

Thus one can naturally say you seem to walk, you seem to will to walk, you seem to have walked.

But what of the case of I would walk? The closest grammatically proper construction that I can think of would have to be you seem LIKE you would walk.

See titular question

Comment: How exactly is this off topic?

Comment: Not voting up or down, but noting that the question makes assumptions: "You seem to will to walk" is not quite right. And the word *will* usually sets other verbs in the future (not *I willed myself to stand*). As a helper verb, it doesn't form an infinitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the use of main verbs with that of auxiliary verbs.

*Have*, *will*, and *would* are auxiliary verbs helping the main verb *walk* here.

*Will* (as an auxiliary) and *would* are [“defective” verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb); they have no infinitive form or inflections for tense and number.

Answer (score 4):

"Would" (in "I would walk") is a verb, specifically a **modal auxiliary verb.** The same goes for "will" in "I will walk," though in other senses "will" can be used as an ordinary lexical verb. "Have" in "I have walked" is also an auxiliary verb, but not a modal one. In their auxiliary senses, "have" has an infinitive form, but "will" and "would" do not.

There are two ways of understanding this sort of sentence:

1. First, you can see "walk" as the main verb of the sentence, with "would" acting as a dependent that modifies its meaning; Huddleston & Pullum (2002) call this the "dependent-auxiliary analysis."
2. Secondly, you can see "would" as the main verb of the sentence, one which has "walk" as a a bare infinitival complement (i.e. an infinitive phrase without the "to" before the infinitive). Huddleston & Pullum call this the "catenative-auxiliary analysis."

Huddleston & Pullum adopt the catenative-auxiliary analysis, but most traditional accounts of English grammar take the dependent-auxiliary approach.