# Adverbs in the Middle Position BUT WHERE?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

In the book English Grammar in Use, on page number 220. there is - *If the verb is two or more words (for example, can remember / will be cancelled), the **adverb usually goes after the first verb** (can/doesn’t/will, etc.)*.
for example: *The meeting **will probably** be cancelled*, *I **can never** remember her name*.
according to this explanation, can I say **'He must really have understood'**?
I even searched for it and found that 'He must have **really** understood' is more correct.
My question is how to find the perfect position for the middle position adverbs(frequency adverbs, Degree adverbs, evaluate adverbs)?

Comment: There is no single "perfect position". The adverb's position will depend on context, tone and emphasis. It will also depend on whether the adverb is acting as a free modifier or bound modifier.

Comment: *the adverb **usually** goes after the first verb* might be true on average, but there will be any number of exceptions. Written instances of [***must really have,really must have***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=must+really+have%2Creally+must+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) have been about equally common for a century...

Comment: ...but there's been a huge [*shift from **will really have** to **really will have***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+really+have%2Creally+will+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=10), and this looks like a rare case where [Brits are ahead of the linguistic curve.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+really+have%2Creally+will+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=10)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - perhaps worth noting in in your first that [***must have really*** has become more popular recently](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=must+really+have%2Creally+must+have%2Cmust+have+really&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) while [***will have really*** has not](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+really+have%2Creally+will+have%2Cwill+have+really&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

Comment: @Henry: Yeah - I never charted for ***really*** as the *last* word, but it turns out ***must have really*** has come up from nowhere to total domination! But it's odd that with  ***must have,*** we prefer ***really*** at the start, but with ***will have*** we (especially, *Brits*) strongly favour putting ***really*** at the end of the sequence. You'd think there ought to be some identifiable *reason* for such a marked preference, but it certainly escapes me.

Comment: If that lot doesn't confuse the OP, then nothing will!

Comment: It's really confusing to me :( , nothing is definite in making these structures. ~ BillJ 
and @FumbleFingers there are many verbs that are used with adverbs differently, there is no definite structure rule. how can I learn this?

Comment: *I don't really know.* OR *I really don't know*. But I think many native speakers would agree with me that the two examples at the start of this comment ***do*** convey different nuances. To my ear, the first is relatively "unassuming", almost "deferential" - speaker is "hesitatingly" admitting he's not an authority on the subject (but *very likely* speaker will go on to say what he ***thinks**, but doesn't **know for sure***). The second version is far more emphatic, and is more likely if speaker doesn't even intend to hazard a guess. But maybe not everyone makes that distinction, I dunno.

Comment: ... ***that*** distinction arises from the fact that ***really*** by default modifies the word immediately following, so my first version implies I lack ***real, authoritative** knowledge*, whereas the second emphasizes how ***really, definitely** true* it is that I don't know (by implication, don't know *anything*, since the knowledge itself hasn't been "qualified" in that version).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think it's all about expressing your intentions or feelings. different structures carry different nuances. so the more somebody reads the more they get exposure to these structures.

Comment: You've just given yourself advice as good as anything I could say! The more you read (even better, the more you *listen*, as long as you can maintain a reasonable level of understanding in real-time as people are speaking) the better you'll get at choosing the most appropriate word order. Your *written* English text here looks pretty good to me, so I'm guessing you should be able to follow real-time English speech well enough that you can listen to discussion programs, podcasts, etc. of subjects that actually *interest* you - whilst effortlessly gaining subconscious familiarity with usages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though middle position adverbs usually go after the first auxiliary, they don't always. In particular, it can depend on which verb the adverb is modifying.

When an adverb occurs after an auxiliary verb, it is often ambiguous whether the verb is modifying the auxiliary or the verb after it. When an auxiliary is relatively devoid of independent meaning, like the perfect marker *have,* it often doesn't make a difference which verb the adverb is modifying, but it can make a difference when an auxiliary is a modal like *must* (Huddleston & Pullum (2002), pp. 782-783).

So consider these three examples:

1. He really must have understood.
2. He must really have understood.
3. He must have really understood.

Now, when *really* is modifying *must,* the sentence means something like "He has definitely understood it." But when *really* is modifying *have* or *understood,* the sentence means something like "He has thoroughly understood it." It's a bit more complicated than that, since adverbs are sometimes positioned "incongruently," i.e. modifying syntactically a verb that they don't logically modify in terms of meaning, as in sentences like "He must have undoubtedly misinterpreted her letter," but those are the default interpretations (*ibid.,* pp. 783-784).

Putting this all together: in version (1), *really* can only be modifying *must,* so the sentence most likely means "He has definitely understood it." In version (3), *really* can be modifying either *have* or *understood*; either way, the sentence most likely means "He has thoroughly understood it." Version (2) is equally likely to have either interpretation, since there *really* could be modifying either *must* or *have.*

Incidentally, this is part of why many grammarians think that "will be cancelled" is not a single multi-word verb, but rather a series of nested subordinate clauses, so that the syntax of "It will be cancelled" is "It [will [be [cancelled]]]." See my answer about this "catenative-auxiliary" analysis [here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/609567/470858)

Comment: I agree that (3) almost certainly means 'He must have understood thoroughly', though I don't see that 'really' can modify an auxiliary. I see (1) as the intensifier usage, 'There's no denying it, he must have understood.'  ... But (2) can be a corrective: 'He said he hadn't a clue what was going on. But then he moves away from the Ukraine. He must really have understood.' ('The truth must be that he really did understand.' ... As well as a duplicate of (1), or (3).