# What part of speech is the word "having" in this context?

Tags: grammar, phrases, sentence, parts-of-speech, gerund-phrases

What part of speech is the word "having" in the following?

> Having signed the contract, we went for a party.

Comment: Why would you ever imagine it anything but a verb? Only verbs have direct objects.

Comment: Is it a gerund?

Comment: Gerund is not  part of speech.

Comment: My bad. In that case my question is wrong.

Comment: Would you please tell me if its a gerund?

Comment: 'Having' is an **auxiliary verb**. It is part of the **verb phrase** "having signed," where 'signed' is the *main verb*. The auxiliary "having" is in the present participle form (the infinitive is "to have"), *not* the gerund form, because the verb phrase is functioning as an adjective and not a noun. The entire verb phrase ("having signed") is the perfect (active) participle form of "to sign." Does that clarify things?

Comment: Maybe you'll find this helpful? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb

Comment: Various people on the site reject the term 'gerund', but for different reasons. Mine is that it has different definitions among those who use it, so it's unhelpful. // //'**Perfect Participle Clauses**
Perfect participle clauses use the perfect form of a verb and can be used in active or passive sentences. For example:

• Having received the email, George instantly opened it.' [[Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/grammar/participle-clauses/)]

Comment: If you go [here](https://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html) and type in your sentence and hit Submit, it will come back and tell you the constituency parse that you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

*Having* is a verb. Traditionally we would call it a participle; some authors, like [Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), would call it a "gerund-participle," since modern English doesn't cleanly distinguish between gerunds and present participles.

*Having* is being used to mark the perfect aspect, as it does in the sentence "We have signed the contract." The verb *have* in this sense takes as a complement a past-participial clause; in your example, as in "We have signed the contract," that complement is "signed the contract." (According, at least, to the [catenative-auxiliary analysis.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/609567/470858))